# octobercms install error: database is not empty?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, laravel, octobercms

I want to try laravel octobercms,my database has some wordpress field, when I install october, I got error :

```
Database "###" is not empty. Please empty the database or specifyanother database.
There is a problem with the specified Database configuration.
```

I do not know how to do. I do not want to empty my database,what should I do ?

PS.I use virtual host, only one Database.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is manditory for OctoberCMS to start with an empty database. Maybe you can start from an empty database and import the wordpress shenanigans later as an alternative solution.